# Can I get into an Australian PhD program in computer science without a masters degree, with a dual BSc degree?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, computer-science, australia

I am following a dual degree program in my home country (Sri Lanka). One degree, B.Sc in Computer Science will be awarded by an Australian University and the other degree which is a B.Sc (Hons) in Software Engineering will be awarded by my home country University.

Will I be able to get in to an Australian PhD program without doing Masters with these two degrees?

Comment: PhD program where? Since many (most?) US PhD programs do not require a master's degree, you should be able to meet the requirements of a US-based program. I can't say what will happen for European programs that require a prior master's degrees.

Comment: I'm looking for an Australian PhD program

Comment: And your home country?

Comment: My home country is Sri Lanka

Answer (score 5):

I am an Australian PhD student. Most of my fellow students do not have a Masters.

My university lists the requirements for a PhD [here](http://www.jcu.edu.au/grs/prospective/entry/index.htm)

Of particular note:

> 1.1.4 To be eligible to apply for entry to a Doctoral program, an applicant must demonstrate the capacity to undertake research at the Doctoral level by the attainment of at least one of the following:
>
> (i) A Bachelor’s degree with at least Second Class, Division A (Honours) in a degree program that included a total of at least a semester of supervised project work, the results of which contributed to the Honours grade;
>
> (ii) A postgraduate qualification which included: (a) supervised research component(s) of at least one semester or equivalent and resulted in the production of output(s) graded at the equivalent of Distinction or better, and (b) at least one research methods subject;
>
> (iii) A Research Masters degree, where at least two thirds of the degree consisted of a supervised research component and resulted in the production of a thesis or equivalent;
>
> (iv) Enrolment at this or another Australian university in a higher degree by research for the equivalent of at least 0.5 EFTSL with demonstrated satisfactory performance in the supervised research component(s);
>
> (v) A combination of qualifications, research training and experience, considered equivalent to the above by the Responsible Academic Officer in the Enrolling Organisational Unit, e.g., senior authorship of at least one peer-reviewed publication plus completion of an appropriate research methods subject.

Most of the time people who get in appear to have either first class honours or some published research. I have seen domestic students with a lower GPA work with a supervisor to publish some research in order to be accepted into the PhD.

Comment: We also recently admitted a PhD student from the United States at my Go8 Uni with no masters, but he had research components and good recommendation letters.

Answer (score 0):

Some universities let the applicants, possessing solid background from their undergraduate studies, apply for direct Ph.D.

As a matter of fact, the number of the obtained B.Sc. degrees does not matter, considerably. You better check the possibility for pursing direct Ph.D. with communicating with the coordinator of the target program.

It is suffice to say that, your proved potential ability for research (by means of any published research paper) in addition to a fascinating transcript might be necessary to hit this mark.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on your grades or GPA.  If you finish with First Class Honours, then you will have no problem getting into a PhD degree in Australia.